# Get full path of selected file in Internet Explorer (path is visible)

Tags: javascript, html

Yeah I know this may be a duplicate, but all previous posts regarding this were for Chrome or Firefox .. I'm asking for Internet Explorer only, as that's the browser my client uses for the localhost web-app we're making for them ...

Basically I have a HTML file selection control in place ...

`<input type="file"  name="vestingFileBrowse" id="vestingFileBrowse"/>`

... and I want to extract the full path of the file that has been selected.

Note that unlike Chrome, for Internet Explorer, the full path is displayed on the form once the user chooses a file .. So in theory, is it not possible to simply read the value of that text box control, to get the full path ?

Note that I **cannot use jQuery**, or any other 3rd party library, due to the project's requirements ..

Also, I cannot add the localhost site as a Trusted Site in Internet Explorer, due to requirements ... (Otherwise IE would've given the full path instead of `C:\fakepath\...`)

Comment: _"..as that's the browser my client uses for the localhost web-app we're making for them..."_ So they **have a choice**. Here's how I'd deal with it. Tell them that IE is old and insecure, if they want support is going to cost them a 50% premium. That's one way of solving the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in a position to make such demands :)

Comment: I usually dealt with this telling them to phone microsoft to get this feature done... It is NOT your software, you do not have rights on it nor did you ever want to program it so direct them to the correct persons if they want a feature fixed or created...

Comment: Create a ClickOnce application instead. Because it feels like you're trying to use web-technology for something it isn't created for.